# Second i2c bus on RPi 3?

Tags: pi-3b+

Were you ever successful big-banging a second i2c bus on the RPi 3?  I've seen different sites showing a 'dtoverlay', but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I see a result of a "i2cdetect -y 3" but very very slow, and no devices show up.  I've got a (probably over-large) project for a RPi 3 and need the speed of two i2c buses.  If you have any suggestions, please reply here.  Thanks!!
BTW: I'm using a RPi3 and Stretch.

Comment: I hesitate to use dtoverlay because they might work this OS version but not next.  Also there is no guarantee of technical support.  And have you read the folloing posts? Activating the second I2C bus on Raspberry Pi from Python - Sebastian Ludwig 2014oct9
https://procrastinative.ninja/2014/10/29/activating-the-second-i2c-bus-on-raspberry-pi-from-python/

Using the 2nd I2C bus [ONLY] on the 2B v1.1 - HenriZ 2016feb28 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: Adding multiple software buses using dtoverlay  is the most sensible approach.  Perhaps you would be better off finding out what you did wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Note that we are not a discussion style forum and open ended invitations to brainstorm are not appropriate to the format. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.